# Is it possible to package a batch script into a exe running a tkinter based application?

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, tkinter, pyinstaller

My tkinter application needs to execute a batch script in the backend and the script cannot be exposed.

Can I package the batch script into the application exe when I'm packaging it with `pyinstaller --onefile -w main.py` command?

Or do I need to bring all the commands into my python program function and execute one by one with `subprocess.Popen`

Comment: If you create a one-folder instead of a one-file app, you could include a batch file by [adding it as a data file to the bundle](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle). You could also include the contents of a batch file as a literal string in your Python source code and use it to create the file on-demand — the latter approach would allow you to create a one-file app.

Comment: For the former approach, won't it expose the script?

Comment: Yes — why would that be a problem? Even if you did a one-file, it'll only be a little harder to get to.